# Sort the column values and search the value

Tags: perl

Input to my script is this file which contains data as below.

```
A food 75
B car 136
A car 69
A house 179
B food 75
C car 136
C food 85
```

For each distinct value of the second column, I want to print any line where the number in the third column is different.

Example output

```
C food 85 
A car 69
```

Here is my Perl code.

```perl
#! /usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warning;

my %data = ();

open FILE, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;
while ( <FILE> ) {
    chomp;
    $data{$1} = $2 while /\s*(\S+),(\S+)/g;
}
close FILE;

print $_, '-', $data{$_}, $/ for keys %data;
```

I am able to print the hash keys and values, but not able to get the desired output.

Any pointers on how to do that using Perl?

Comment: You forgot to post the script bit

Comment: Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: added my script code

Comment: What happens if you have, say `A food 1` `B food 2` `C food 3`? Are all lines printed, or none?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your question, you want a list of all the lines where there is an "odd one out" with the same item type and a different number in the third column from all the rest

I think this is what you need

It reads all the data into hash `%data`, so that `$data{$type}{$n}` is a (reference to an) array of all the data lines that use that object type and number

Then the hash is scanned again, looking for and printing all instances that have only a single line with the given type/number *and* where there are other values for the same object type (otherwise it would be the only entry and not an "odd one out")

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my %data;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt';

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my ( $label, $type, $n) = split;
    push @{ $data{$type}{$n} }, $_;
}

for my $type ( keys %data ) {

    my $items = $data{$type};

    next unless keys %$items > 1;

    for my $n ( keys %$items ) {
        print $items->{$n}[0] if @{ $items->{$n} } == 1;
    }
}
```

#### output

```
C food 85
A car 69
```

Note that this may print multiple lines for a given object type if the input looks like, say

```
B car 22
A car 33
B car 136
C car 136
```

This has two "odd ones out" that appear only once for the given object type, so both `B car 22` and `A car 33` will be printed

Comment: Thankyou @borodin  it really help and work like a charm

Comment: Hi @borodin how to get output in this format. if i have same input A food 75
B car 136
A car 69
A house 179
B food 75
B car 136
C food 85

output want in below format.
C food 85 not match with A food 75, B food 75
A car 69 not match with  B car 136

Answer (score 0):

Here are the pointers:

First, you need to remember lines somewhere before outputting them.
Second, you need to discard previously remembered line for the object according to the rules you set.
In your case, the rule is to discard when the number for the object differs from the previous remembered.
Both tasks can be accomplished with the [hash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html).

For each line:

```
    my ($letter, $object, $number)=split /\s+/, $line;
    if (!defined($hash{$object}) || $hash{$object}[0]!=$number) {
      $hash{$object}=[$number, $line];
    }
```

Third, you need to output the hash:

```
for my $object(keys %hash) {
    print $hash{$object}[1];
}
```

But there is the problem: a hash is an unordered structure, it won't return its keys in the order you put them into the hash.
So, the fourth: you need to add the ordering to your hash data, which can be accomplished like this:

```
  $hash{$object}=[$number,$line,$.]; # $. is the row number over all the input files or STDIN, we use it for sorting
```

And in the output part you sort with the stored row number
(see [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for details about `$a`, `$b` variables):

```
for my $object(sort { $hash{$a}[2]<=>$hash{$b}[2] } keys %hash) {
    print $hash{$object}[1];
}
```

**Regarding the comments**

I am certain that my code does not contain any errors.
If we look at the question before it was edited by some high rep users, it states:

[cite]
Now where if Numeric column(Third) has different value (Where in 2nd column matches) ...Then print only the mismatched number line. example..
    **A food 75**
    B car 136
    A car 69
    A house 179
    **B food 75**
    B car 136
    **C food 85**

Example output (As number columns are not matching)
    **C food 85**
[/cite]

I can only interpret that `print only the mismatched number line` as: to print the last line for the object where the number changed. That clearly matches the example the OP provided.

Even so, in my answer I addressed the possibility of misinterpretation, by stating that line omitting is done according to whatever rules the OP wants.
And below that I indicated what was the rule by that time *in my opinion*.
I think it well addressed the OP problem, because, after all, *the OP wanted the pointers*.

And now my answer is critiqued because it does not match the edited (long after and not by OP) requirements.

I disagree.

Regarding the whitespace: specifying `/\s+/` for split *is not an error here*, despite of some comments trying to assert that.
While I agree that `" "` is common for split, I would disagree that there are a lot of cases where you *must* use `" "` instead of `/\s+/`.
`/\s+/` is a regular expression which is the conventional argument for split, while `" "` is the shorthand, that actually masks the meaning.
With that I decided to use explicit `split /\s+/, $line` in my example instead of just `split " ", $line` or just `split` *specifically to show the innerworkings of perl*.

I think it is important to any one new to perl.

It is perfectly ok to use `/\s+/`, but be careful if you expect to have leading whitespace in your data, consult `perldoc -f split` and decide whether `/\s+/` suits your needs or not.

Comment: `split /\s+/, $line` should almost always be `split " ", $line`

Comment: I chose `/\s+/` deliberately, so the meaning of that argument would be more explicit and clear to a person new to perl.

Comment: Also, your code will just print the last value for each `$object`. If the OP's data had `A car 69` before the rest of the data then your code would show `B car 136`

Comment: And I wrote the code when the answer wasn't edited yet to include this statement *For each distinct value of the second column, I want to print any line where the number in the third column is different.* , which changed the requirement.

Comment: The error of using `/\s+/` instead of `" "`, which will fail if there is any leading whitespace on the input line. Even the OP's code allows for that!

Comment: That's my edit. The original post was a mess, and said *"Then print only the mismatched number line"*, and the example shows `A car 69` being printed.

Comment: I don't see any leading whitespace in the OP data and nothing suggests it is going to be there. You are trying to add uncommon corner cases to the problem where it's not necessary. I may well do the same and say that the `" "` will fail if the letter column contains empty value, which is a corner case also.

Comment: If you want to allow for embedded white space then you need to ask for more precise details of the format, and in that case your variant won't work either. It is far better to assume that the OP's code is a reasonable indication of what may be there. It is commonly recognised that `split " ", $_` is the most appropriate way to split a string on white space: that is why it is the default for `split`. Please stop arguing with me for the sake of saving face.

Comment: Your code also prints `A house 179` which shouldn't be in the output.

Comment: I get from your code `A house 179
C food 85
B car 136` which only correctly finds the different record if it follows the duplicates. `car 136` should be `car 69`

Comment: @ChrisCharley I wrote my code with the assumption that the OP needed the last line where the number differed from previous line for the same object. So for the `car` it should be the second `B car 136` because it differs from previous `A car 69` (and we _do not take_ the first column into account).   So far there were no indications from the OP that he wanted something else.

Comment: Ok, that's the way you read it but in his desired output he had `C food 85
A car 69` so I assumed he wanted only the ones that differed from the like ones. His data sample leaves something to be desired.

Comment: Well in the editing history the first version didn't include `A car 69`.  That's what I based my code on. Anyway, the OP wanted the guidance, not the exact solution to the exact problem.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get the output in this format.C food 85 not matching with A Food 75 , B food 75. it print for the same item(e.g Food) in one line by comparing their values.

Comment: @Sonal You'd better post another question with sample input data and desired results. See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) about how to format a question for easier understanding. (You can also click on edit button of your question and see how the formatting was done).